# When using .net MVC RadioButtonFor(), how do you group so only one selection can be made?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

This one has me stumped, I have a strongly typed view that has this loop to generate radiobuttons:

```
<% foreach (QuestionAnswer qa in Model.QuestionAnswers)
   { %>
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.QuestionAnswers[(int)qa.QuestionID - 1].AnswerValue, "Checked" ) %>
    <%= Html.Encode(qa.OptionValue) %>
<% } %>
```

It renders fine, but since the names are not the same, you can select more than 1 radiobutton.  How can I group them so only 1 radiobutton can be selected?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you use `Html.RadioButton` instead?

Comment: Since it's a strongly-typed view I am trying to make it so the data comes back populated to the controller.

I'm open to any suggestions though!

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The first parameter of Html.RadioButtonFor() should be the property name you're using, and the second parameter should be the value of that specific radio button. Then they'll have the same name attribute value and the helper will select the given radio button when/if it matches the property value.

**Example:**

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "M" ) %> Male
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "F" ) %> Female
</div>
```

**Here's a more specific example:**

I made a quick MVC project named "DeleteMeQuestion" (DeleteMe prefix so I know that I can remove it later after I forget about it).

I made the following model:

```
namespace DeleteMeQuestion.Models
{
    public class QuizModel
    {
        public int ParentQuestionId { get; set; }
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionDisplayText { get; set; }
        public List<Response> Responses { get; set; }

        [Range(1,999, ErrorMessage = "Please choose a response.")]
        public int SelectedResponse { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public int ResponseId { get; set; }
        public int ChildQuestionId { get; set; }
        public string ResponseDisplayText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There's a simple range validator in the model, just for fun. Next up, I made the following controller:

```
namespace DeleteMeQuestion.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            // TODO: get question to show based on method parameter 
            var model = GetModel(id);
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int? id, QuizModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var freshModel = GetModel(id);
                return View(freshModel);
            }

            // TODO: save selected answer in database
            // TODO: get next question based on selected answer (hard coded to 999 for now)

            var nextQuestionId = 999;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {id = nextQuestionId});
        }

        private QuizModel GetModel(int? questionId)
        {
            // just a stub, in lieu of a database

            var model = new QuizModel
            {
                QuestionDisplayText = questionId.HasValue ? "And so on..." : "What is your favorite color?",
                QuestionId = 1,
                Responses = new List<Response>
                                                {
                                                    new Response
                                                        {
                                                            ChildQuestionId = 2,
                                                            ResponseId = 1,
                                                            ResponseDisplayText = "Red"
                                                        },
                                                    new Response
                                                        {
                                                            ChildQuestionId = 3,
                                                            ResponseId = 2,
                                                            ResponseDisplayText = "Blue"
                                                        },
                                                    new Response
                                                        {
                                                            ChildQuestionId = 4,
                                                            ResponseId = 3,
                                                            ResponseDisplayText = "Green"
                                                        },
                                                }
            };

            return model;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I made the following view that makes use of the model:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<DeleteMeQuestion.Models.QuizModel>" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

        <div>

            <h1><%: Model.QuestionDisplayText %></h1>

            <div>
            <ul>
            <% foreach (var item in Model.Responses) { %>
                <li>
                    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedResponse, item.ResponseId, new {id="Response" + item.ResponseId}) %>
                    <label for="Response<%: item.ResponseId %>"><%: item.ResponseDisplayText %></label>
                </li>
            <% } %>
            </ul>

            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedResponse) %>

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

As I understand your context, you have questions with a list of available answers. Each answer will dictate the next question. Hopefully that makes sense from my model and TODO comments.

This gives you the radio buttons with the same name attribute, but different ID attributes.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but I think the name field is causing the problem since it is part of a loop.  When I look at the source, it shows AnswerValue[1], AnswerValue[2], etc...

To be able to return the Strongly Typed result this naming is necessary (I would like to store each radio button in it's own field).  Just wondered if there was any way to make only a single selection functionality.

Comment: Can you share a slim version of your model's class definition and intent? Is your code loop tasked with creating radio buttons for a single question and all of its answers? Which property stores the selected value? Stuff like that would help describe what you want to do.

Comment: I'm still in the development stages, so open to solutions.  Basically we want to present questions to the user with multiple choice results drawn from a DB.  Each result is a question as well, with the parentQuestionID being the main question.

Slimmed Model would be public class QuestionAnswer { public int QuesitonID {}, public string QuestionText {}, public string OptionValue {}, public string AnswerValue {}.

I would pass a list of this model in.  I've added my loop code to the original question.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, my problem was that the selected value was not stored in the parent question, but each value had it's own questionID.  I had to use the name property, but you have given me an idea to model with a separate table to hold option values.

Thanks a lot for your help and I think the new model will work better anyways, especially if it means I can do a strongly typed result.

Comment: Hi a7drew, what if we have a couple of RadioButtons for some property Property in a class. But I am displaying a collection of objects that belongs to that particular class. For an example List of Persons with each having detail for Gender to choose from. More than one <div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "M" ) %> Male
    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "F" ) %> Female
</div> Elements on the page. I hope it make sense...

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had a collection of radio buttons that needed to be in a group.
I just included a 'Selected' property in the model. Then, in the loop to output the radiobuttons just do...

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.Selected, Model.Categories[i].Title)
```

This way, the name is the same for all radio buttons. When the form is posted, the 'Selected' property is equal to the category title (or id or whatever) and this can be used to update the binding on the relevant radiobutton, like this...

```
model.Categories.Find(m => m.Title.Equals(model.Selected)).Selected = true;
```

May not be the best way, but it does work.

Answer (score -6):

In cases where the name attribute is different it is easiest to control the radio group via JQuery. When an option is selected use JQuery to un-select the other options.

Comment: This goes against the intended use of the radio button name property and adds an unnecessary dependency on JQuery.