# Templated list with radio buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I have the following code:

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Themes.Count; i++)
                    {

                    <div class="theme">
                        <img src="/Content/img/placeholder/@Model.Themes[i].PreviewImg" class="theme-image" />
                        <div class="theme-meta">
                            @Html.RadioButton("Themes", Model.Themes[i].Selected, new { @id = "Themes_" + i + "__Selected" })

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Themes[i].Id)
                            <label>@Model.Themes[i].Name</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    }
                    <div class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" class="dash-module-alt-button submit" name="SelectTheme" />
                    </div>
                }
```

However submitting this with one of the radio buttons selected does not bind with the selected property set to true.

Using Html.RadioButtonFor means that they all have a generated array name so they can all be selected.

HOW the eff am i supposed to do this?

cheers

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but `Html.RadioButtonFor` will take a value argument -

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Themes, "blue")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Themes, "green")
```

A method for using this in a loop is discussed in this question - [When using .net MVC RadioButtonFor(), how do you group so only one selection can be made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114689/when-using-net-mvc-radiobuttonfor-how-do-you-group-so-only-one-selection-can)