# Radiobuttonfor to select only one option between multiple options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have this model which contains 2 booleans:

```
public bool m_IsOptionA {get;set;}
public bool m_IsOptionB {get;set;}
```

And, in my view, I want to generate 2 radio buttons, and the user must select either one or the other. So, basically, I need to make it so that if one is selected, the other gets unchecked.

In my controller, before passing my model to the view, I initialize theses values like this for each items of the list of objects:

```
foreach (var item in m_ListObjs)
{
    item.m_IsOptionA = true;
    item.m_IsOptionB = false;
}
```

Then, in my view, I generate this code for the radiobuttons:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <p>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x[i].m_IsOptionA, new{id = "m_IsAuction_true"}, new {style = "width:100px"})</td>
                <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x[i].m_IsOptionB, new{id = "m_IsBuyItNow_false"}, new {style = "width:130px"})</td>
            </tr>
        </p>
    }
```

But they can both be checked and remained checked once they are checked, which is not the behavior I want.

Do I need some javascript? Is so, how could I do this, and if not, what did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Why have radio buttons, surely a checkbox is better. If checked optionA is true and b false. if unchecked then the other way around.

Comment: Well, it could be an option, too. It's just that I've never worked with radiobuttons and want to learn how. And, anyway, with this behavior, I'd also need to make sure that if one checkbox is checked, the other gets unchecked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114689/when-using-net-mvc-radiobuttonfor-how-do-you-group-so-only-one-selection-can - this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Thanks to @Digger37, I understood my mistake. I do not need to have 2 booleans, but rather one and 2 radiobuttons for each values wanted.

Here's my boolean:

```
public bool m_IsOptionSelected {get;set;}
```

and now here is my new view:

```
<td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x[i].m_IsOptionSelected , "true", new {style = "width:100px"}) Option A</td>
<td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x[i].m_IsOptionSelected , "false", new {style = "width:100px"}) Option B</td>
```

And it works perfectly. Thanks!