# Change <input> to @Html.RadioButtonFor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, radio-button

Quite a simple question, but struggling to find an answer for it. How do I convert

```
<input type="radio" id="radAnswer" name="answer" value="@answer" />
```

to

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(/*some sort of code in here*/)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

something like

```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.answer, your value, new { @id= "radAnswer" , @class="any"})
```

for new property define in new  like for checked radiobutton

```
 new { Checked = "checked"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RadioButtonFor` as follows

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.answer,"Answer",new { id = "radAnswer" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114689/when-using-net-mvc-radiobuttonfor-how-do-you-group-so-only-one-selection-can), can help you, it's not the same but give a good understanding of how the `@Html.RadioButtonFor` syntax works.