# Input data is not returning by passing through object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am passing the input data from the .cshtml page to the action method.

Here is my .cshtml page:

```
@model passingdata

<form asp-controller="Home"  method="post" asp-action="About" >
   <button class="btn-danger" type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <input asp-for="date" placeholder="Date" class="col-md-8" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Select from these Four Classes
        <input type="radio" name="class" asp-for="classselect1" id="classselect1" value="classselect1" class="col-md-4" /> <p> @Model.classname1</p>
        <input type="radio" name="class" asp-for="classselect2" id="classselect2" value="classselect2" class="col-md-4" /> <p> @Model.classname2</p>
        <input type="radio" name="class" asp-for="classselect3" id="classselect3" value="classselect3" class="col-md-4" /> <p> @Model.classname3</p>
        <input type="radio" name="class" asp-for="classselect4" id="classselect4" value="classselect4" class="col-md-4" /> <p> @Model.classname4</p>
      </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here is my controller code which is invoked when i Click on the button.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult About(passingdata p)
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
    Teacher.classselect1 = p.classselect1;
    Teacher.classselect2 = p.classselect2;
    Teacher.classselect3 = p.classselect3;
    Teacher.classselect4 = p.classselect4;
    Teacher.date = p.date;
    return View();
}
```

The input data like date and bool value from the radiobutton is not passing through the object of the class which contain these variables.
Please help me in this.

Comment: Please post the `passingdata` class code.

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly, the Name attribute of each radiobutton is how .net MVC will map the values to your model.

In this case, all of your names are "class", which essentially means you have 1 form field named class with 4 options.

I would recommend using the html helper classes, because they will automatically create the proper html for you. The answer to this post should help: [When using .net MVC RadioButtonFor(), how do you group so only one selection can be made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114689/when-using-net-mvc-radiobuttonfor-how-do-you-group-so-only-one-selection-can)

If you dont want to use the helper just remember that when you submit a form, the data that is posted is based on the name of each form field. .Net does some magic in the background to serialize your Model for you, but essentially you are just submitting data in the format "?prop1=val1&prop2=val2".

**Update**
I figure maybe I should clarify a little better why what you are doing is not working how you expect.

When you post or put data via a form, it passes the input fields (text box, radio button, checkbox, etc...) as either querystring params or are part of the body. Radio buttons work a little differently than other input type. For a radio button, there are multiple input elements, but only one of them is valid. That is handled by using the name attribute. In your case, all of the names are "class", which means that the only thing being passed to the server is a single "?class={val}" (val is the value of which ever radio button is selected).

If your passingdata model had a property called "class", it would be populated. If your goal is to populated all 4 of the classselect properties with different values, you would need the name of each radio button to be different. But if there was only one radio button with each name, then each property could only have 1 value. You would need multiple RadioButtons with the same name to have multiple values (only one of which is selectable for each property).

Hopefully that clarifies what is wrong and gets you in the right direction.