# How do I add multiple words after RadioButtonFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying something which should be easy

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Prop, false) Option One
```

I am following the example on [When using .net MVC RadioButtonFor(), how do you group so only one selection can be made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114689/when-using-net-mvc-radiobuttonfor-how-do-you-group-so-only-one-selection-can)

The problem is, it doesn't render and I get an error message in the browser explaining it expects a `;`

Why can't I have this? What do I need to do to show both words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell razor that "Option one" is a plain text you want to use in your html markup, not part of any C# statement/code you are executing. One way is to wrap that in an existing html element.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Prop,"Detroit") <span>Option One</span>
```

Or Explicitly specify the non code part(plain text) using `@:` tag when using with other code.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Prop,"Detroit") @:Option One
```

Comment: This great and works, but does `@;` have a name?  I was unable to find this in my searches?

Comment: `@:` is used to mix C# code and plain text. See this link for reference http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/