# How to pass radio button value to controller from view in MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a couple of radio buttons in my MVC application and I have applied css styling to display images instead of the actual radio button circles. I am stuck on finding a way to pass the selected radio button value to the controller. I have tried looking for a solution online but couldn't find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@model xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.AddEmployeeCommand

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EmployeeDetails", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<label class="label"> Name </label>  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)

<input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="Male" name="item" id="Male">
<label class="label_item" for="Male">
<img src="~/Images/Test1.png" width="40" height="40" />
</label>

<input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="Female" name="item" id="Female">
<label class="label_item" for="Female">
<img src="~/Images/Test2.png" width="40" height="40" />
</label>
}
```

Here is my CSS

```
.radio_item {
    display: none !important;
}
.label_item {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.radio_item:checked + label {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is my controller class,

```
public class EmployeeDetailsController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(AddEmployeeCommand command)
    {       

        employeeCommandHandler.Save(command);
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your radio buttons do not have any value (there is nothing to pass to the controller!)

Comment: What does your controller action method model looks like, when you hit submit? Please update your html to show us the complete form.

Comment: Now that you have added values, it will post back (and bind to a model property or parameter `string item`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry but how do I bind it to a model property? My model has a property 'Gender'

Comment: How would a something named `item` bind to something named `Gender` :) ALWAYS use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to generate the html (your radio buttons need `name="Gender"` to bind to a property named `Gender`)

Comment: `@Hrml.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Male", new { @class="radio_item", id = "male" })`

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you for your answer. That worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind all the radio options in a group ie. to the same property. You can then post this to the controller/Action..

Refer below link it will help..
[When using .net MVC RadioButtonFor(), how do you group so only one selection can be made?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114689/when-using-net-mvc-radiobuttonfor-how-do-you-group-so-only-one-selection-can)

Comment: OP already has grouped them (both radio buttons have `name="item"` !) This has nothing to do with the issue.